# Removing random repeated guesses from brute force program

Tags: java, random

I came here to ask if there is a way to prevent already guessed guesses from being guessed again in my brute-force Java program. Basically I used a `rand.nextInt` in my program but the program will guess already guessed passwords again even if they were incorrect. How could I prevent this as it wastes time and processing power to guess already guessed numbers?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class pwcracker
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    Random rand = new Random();



  String pw, choices, guess;
    long tries;
    int j, length;

    System.out.println("Enter a password that is up to 5 chars and contains no numbers: ");
    pw = "" + scan.nextLine();
    length = pw.length();

    choices = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    tries = 0;
    guess = "";

    System.out.println("Your pw is: " + pw);
    System.out.println("The length of your pw is: " + length);

  System.out.println("for TEST- Guess: " + guess + "pw :"+pw);


  if (!guess.equals(pw)){

  while  (!guess.equals(pw)) 
    { 
        j = 0;
        guess = "";

        while ( j < length )
        {
            guess = guess + choices.charAt( rand.nextInt( choices.length() ) ); 
        j = j + 1;

        if (guess .equals(pw))
     {
       System.out.println("Match found, ending loop..");
       break;
     }

        }
                System.out.println("Guess: " + guess + " pw :"+pw);     
        tries = tries + 1;                      
    }
  }
    System.out.println("Here is your password: " + guess);
    System.out.println("It took " + tries + " tries to guess it.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways.

1. Use a sequence which ensures values are not repeated.

E.g. aaaaa, aaaab, aaaac ... aaaay, aaaaz, aaaba, aaabb, aaabc etc

2. Keep track of the previously attempted values (e.g. using a HashSet variable) and skip the check when it's already been tried.  However, I would have thought that the memory and extra processing used in this method make it pretty pointless since you will normally waste more resources than you will save.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is the use of randomisation - it's not really a brute-force attack if you are guessing.

If it were a 4-digit combination lock you would start at 0000 and then try 0001 and 0002 and so on. That's the brute-force approach. I suggest that you employ exactly the same approach with your password cracker. It should be the same algorithm, but rather than 10 posibilities in each slot you have 26.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: keep an ordered array that you do a binary search over to find if you asked the same password. If you're going over a small keyspace, I actually don't think that doing the random iteration is going to help you so I don't know why not go sequentially. As for the optimal solution for a more complex version, you should be storing hashes (SHA/MD5/SHA2/etc) of passwords attempted in partial directories based on the resultant hash prefixes:

```
md5(pass) = "hashval"
search:
  h\
    a\
      s\
        h\
          ordered_content.txt (contains all "hash*" hashes in alphabetical order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whichever way you decide to implement this, keep in mind that it will take some amount of processing time.  If the time it takes to test a randomly generated password is very low you might end up with a worse runtime.

The longer the process runs (the more of the total search space you check) the more inefficient the random method gets, though, as you will hit duplicates more often.